# How to display all image in a folder with a shortcode for a wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

How do you insert an image from the server folder to the wordpress post with a shortcode, (i don't wanna insert image manually) ?

I've search from google, and see the plugin that approached my desire:

wordpress.org/plugins/folder-gallery/

an example of using this plugin's shortcode is:
[foldergallery folder = "wp-content/uploads/cars"]

(the plugin search for folder cars, and show the image content)

it's good, the plugin will show gallery with lots of thumbnails, 
example result:

but this is not what i want.

I want the result is all image in a folder will show up with full size in the post.

is somebody here know another plugin or another way to make it happen, or maybe to create own shortcode to show full image size?

thanks,
Gerga

Answer (score 0):

Just add the HTML anywhere in the post (preferably in he HTML mode of the Editor)

```
<img src="/wp-content/folder/car.jpg" style="width: 100%,">
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still not that what i want, the case is I have 1000 images in car folder,

Comment: Ahh I understand, you want access to that folder but don't want to fill the article with Thumbnails or Big size pictures.

Comment: I wanna use shortcode to call the image in folder with full size, so I don't need to use more effort.